# How to re-Bind a GridView in a ASP.Net page as a result of a user control event

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, webusercontrol

I have a web page with a datagrid and a user control.
The user control has an event which the web page subscribes to.
On the user control event I need to rebind the datagrid on the web page.

I'm coming up with all sorts of problems due to extender controls that are attached to the grid indicating that they cannot be registered after prerender so it looks like the user control event occurs to late in the page life cycle. Either way those kinda errors would indicate that I'm on the wrong track completely.

I do not want a reference to my page in the user control if at all possible.

What is the best way to achieve this.

I had tried Binding the grid on PageLoad every time but found that although the Databind happened and the updated data was in the datasource that the grid contents did not reflect this. [Is it the GridView viewstate thats playing with this?]

Ding a full refresh or using a button to the page to rebind the grid allowed me to display the correct value.

Thanks in advance,

Liam

Comment: Normally this is exactly the recommend way. But it seems that the extenders are the problem. Have a look if this helps: http://forums.asp.net/t/1061827.aspx

Comment: Thank you. We are using the Extenders for each row on the grid which adds to the complexity really. A cell in each row of the grid has a drop down extender with items to select that performs actions on the row.

Answer (score 0):

> "I had tried Binding the grid on PageLoad every time but found that
>   although the Databind happened and the updated data was in the
>   datasource that the grid contents did not reflect this. [Is it the
>   GridView viewstate thats playing with this?]".

I think that the answer (in part at least) to this is that the third party control is using callbacks to get back to the server and not postbacks so this may be the issue. As I understand it the grid was binded OK but not rendered. [I hadn't come across the differences between Callbacks and Postbacks until this week!!]

I'm open to correction on this though. :)

Liam